# Javascript object spread with an object that may have undefined objects as data in its properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, spread

Hey I'm trying to fill out an empty placeholder object (which in this case serves as a v-model for vue, but not important exactly to the case).
The object that I'm expanding the original with may or may not have some objects inside it undefined, but i need to keep the structure of the first object no matter the structure of incoming one.
For example
Object 1

```
let object1 = { a : '', b : '', c : {name : 'Mark', title: 'Mr'}}
```

and Object 2 which will sometimes come like this

```
let object2 = { a : 'AAA', b : 'BBB', c : undefined}
```

I need to keep the structure of object 1 even if the other object has the property c undefined.
In this case

```
let object1 = { a : 'AAA', b : 'BBB', c : {name : 'Mark', title: 'Mr'}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Make a copy of `object2` with undefined properties removed.

Comment: I think you probably want to rethink your usage of spread if you have nested objects. Spread will only look at the top level of the object.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking `Object.assign({}, objectWithDefinedC, ObjectWithoutDefinedC)` will merge from left to right. So if you add it before the undefined object it should merge properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to spread the `object2` as first item, then add property `c` as second :

```
  object1={...object2,c:object1.c}
```

or

```
   object1={...object2,  c : object2.c ? object2.c : object1.c}
```

Comment: `object1={...object2,  c : object2.c ? object2.c : object1.c}` 

This one seems to be working quite fine (the first not so...)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use spread syntax you could define a simple helper proxy that filters own keys to those having values other than `undefined`

```js
let object1 = {a: '', b: '', c: {name: 'Mark', title: 'Mr'}}

let object2 = {a: 'AAA', b: 'BBB', c: undefined}


const result = { ...defined(object1), ...defined(object2) }

console.log(result)

function defined(obj) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    ownKeys() {
      return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] !== undefined)
    }
  })
}
```